# Find average for column all except current value

Tags: powerbi, dax, average

I have data like this where every row is a task that certain employee completed and how much time it took them.
| employee | minutes |
| -------- | -------- |
emp1           35
emp1           65
emp2           200
emp1           15
emp3           5
emp1           55
emp1           24
emp3           2

What I have:

I've made a table visual with each employee and their average minutes like this

emp1           38.8
emp2           200
emp3           3.5

What I need:

I would like another column that shows what the average would be without this particular employee's rows such as:

emp1           38.8   5 (average of all the values except Emp1's)
emp2           200    38.8
emp3           3.5    65.7

And if possible another column that shows the percentage effect, like this employee made the average increase by x% or decrease by y%, etc. I feel like I have tried everything and I can't figure it out. Thank you in advance

I've tried a bunch of formulas using ALL, ALLEXCEPT, FILTER. I don't have a good enough understanding to write this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these below 2 measure-

```
avg_other = 
CALCULATE(
    AVERAGE(employee_timing[minutes]),
    FILTER(
        ALL(employee_timing),
        employee_timing[employee] <> MIN(employee_timing[employee])
    )
)
```

and

```
avg_effect = (AVERAGE(employee_timing[minutes]) - [avg_other])/[avg_other]
```

here is the output-

[image]